# Issue when launching parallel activities with azure durable function

Tags: python, azure, azure-durable-functions

i try to Launch a simple azure function in parallel but it doesnt work according to the fan in / fan out model.

```
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):

try:

    parallel_tasks  = []
    parallel_tasks.append(context.call_activity("Hello2","paris"))
    parallel_tasks.append(context.call_activity("Hello2","tokyo"))
    outputs = yield context.task_all(parallel_tasks)
    return outputs
```

my activity hello2:

```
def main(name: str) -> str:
    logging.warning("job launched : "+ name)
    time.sleep(30)
    logging.warning("finished : "+ name)
return f"Hello {name}!"
```

**view of the logging**
[image: view of the logging]

My problem is that when I run the durable function, the activities do not run in parallel but one after the other. I used the example of Azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python

I put a time.sleep in order to see if each activities are running in parallel.

Do you have an idea about how i can i resolve my issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your activity function must be an `asnychronous` function. Using `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`.

```
import logging
import asyncio
async def main(name: str) -> str:
    logging.warning("job launched : "+ name)
    asyncio.sleep(3000)
    logging.warning("finished : "+ name)
    return f"Hello {name}!"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `hello2` activity function is called sequentially so the nature of the execution is one after another. Instead you need to use a loop calling the same activity function for a list of inputs, referring the official microsoft doc's example -

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

myApp = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@myApp.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    # Get a list of N work items to process in parallel.
    work_batch = yield context.call_activity("F1", None)

    parallel_tasks = [ context.call_activity("F2", b) for b in work_batch ]

    outputs = yield context.task_all(parallel_tasks)

    # Aggregate all N outputs and send the result to F3.
    total = sum(outputs)
    yield context.call_activity("F3", total)

@myApp.activity_trigger(input_name="name")    
def main(name: str) -> str:
        logging.warning("job launched : "+ name)
        time.sleep(30)
        logging.warning("finished : "+ name)
    return f"Hello {name}!"
```

The above code should work.